# The "invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive] error" will not go away plz

Tags: c++

I just started learning c++ and I'm having an issue with "invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char'

```
[-fpermissive]" in my source code.

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int
main ()
{
  //Suits
  const string suitList[4] = { "Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds" };
  string suit = suitList[rand() % 4];

  //int suit = 
    //rand ()"Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds";
  //Faces
  char faceList[13] =  {'2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', "10", "Ace", "King", "Queen", "Jack" } ;
  char face = faceList[rand() % 13];

  //int face =
   // rand ()"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Ace", "King", "Queen", "Jack";

  //Dealer
  string Deal;
  cout << "Type Deal for a card: ";
  cin >> Deal;
  cout << "Your card is the " << face << " of " << suit;

  return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out what it is asking me and am very confused right now.

Comment: `char faceList[13]` is an array of characters, yet some of the elements in your initializer list are clearly strings. This cannot work

Comment: My advice is if you are permitted to use `std::string` favor its usage over `char[]`. If you have `c++17` you may also be interested in `std::string_view`: [https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-6a-an-introduction-to-stdstring_view/](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-6a-an-introduction-to-stdstring_view/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
char faceList[13] =  {'2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', "10", "Ace", "King", "Queen", "Jack" } ;
```

doesn't work because you are mixing `char`s and `const char*`, which are like strings.

You could just make them all strings:

```
string faceList[13] =  {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Ace", "King", "Queen", "Jack" } ;
```

Ideally, avoid arrays entirely, and just use `std::vector<std::string>`.